# drupal theme checkboxes

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes

I'm trying to us the theme hook the style some checkboxes. I have used the form_alter hook to make some changes to the labels of each checkbox and now i would like to interact with the checkbox theme function to style the labels.

In the form array it says

```
#theme (String, 20 characters ) select_as_checkboxes
```

is this the function i need to override? And how do i do this?
I tried stuff like

```
function mymodule_select_as_checkboxes()
```

but i can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
   function my_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
      // Register theme_function to use the module custom function
      if (!empty($theme_registry['select_as_checkboxes'])) {
        $theme_registry['select_as_checkboxes']['function'] = 'my_module_select_as_checkboxes';
      }
    }
```

Then in the function my_module_select_as_checkboxes create your own function or adapt the original one.